# Does Visual Studio 2010 exist in different languages?

Tags: language, visual-studio-2010

Does Visual Studio 2010 exist in other languages than English?

I mean, is there a French, German, Chinese versions of Visual Studio 2010, like there are international versions of Windows or Microsoft Office?

It is a bit confusing, since on some Microsoft websites, Visual Studio is marked as available in different languages, but I can't find any screenshot of any Visual Studio window other than an English one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio is available in many languages.

You can take a [look and see the downloads here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx?pv=18:370) even if you do not have a MSDN subscription. Simply change the language near the top right.

[image]

Mind you, every screenshot/demo I have seen, the actual code itself seems to be in English.

Comment: The code is usually in English because the language standards popular in the west specify keywords in English. Some programming languages (like Java and C#) allow some parts of the program to be written in different language or even different script. I know that variables can be written in pretty much anything unicode in Java and C# and I think classes too, but I'm not 100% certain. I know that there are complete translations of some programming languages (like Python in Chinese, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChinesePython) to another human language, but I don't know too much about them.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: names of methods, classes and variables can use any unicode characters, so you're right. Now, if most of the code is written in English, it's because this is the only way to make code which can be used by every developer in the world. Working in France, I have a lot of pain to explain to my coworkers that if they write their code and comments in French, they will be unable to ever work with anyone who does not use French fluently.

Comment: @MainMa Well, it's a trade-off. Is some piece of code ever going to be used by someone from a different language area? If yes, would the use be considerable enough to warrant difficulties for primary developers? Of course, a major project should have clear standards for language use and clear style manual for variable and function names so that after analyzing it other developers can easily understand code even if their English is not so good. Another problem in some languages may be script switching: It's much easier to write int diameter that int ALT+SHIFT (or whatever) пречник ALT+SHIFT.