# Is it possible to install Visual Studio 2010 in a different language?

Tags: language, license, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, license-key

I have a legal Visual Studio 2010 from a French Microsoft website. I thought that it would have an English interface, but [my preceding question](https://superuser.com/questions/184415/does-visual-studio-2010-exist-in-different-languages/184417#184417) shown me that it is not the case.

Since I hate using non-English software, **how can I install an English version instead?**

It would be as easy as getting an installation disk and enter the serial, but since Visual Studio 2010 [does not display or require to enter the serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946885/microsoft-products-such-as-visual-studio-2010-does-not-require-to-enter-serial-nu), I can't do that.